# ShellScript: grep+while+cut+awk in a large file = very slow

Tags: shell, awk, grep, while-loop

I have this script running in a 1.7GB  text file.

```
#!/bin/bash

File1=$1.tmp
File2=$1.modified

grep '^#' $1 > $File2
grep -v '#' $1 > $File1

while read line; do
        column_four=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f4)
        final_line=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f4-5)
        if [ "$column_four" == "0" ]; then
               beginning_line=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1-3)
               final_line=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f4-5)
        else
               final_line=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1-2)
        fi
        linef=$(echo "$beginning_line $final_line")
        echo $linef | awk '{printf "%5.0f%12.4f%12.4f%5.0f%12.4f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' >> $File2
done < $File1
rm -f $File1
```

The problem: it's very, very slow. It creates a new file with columns arranged in a speed of 200KB per minute with a Core2Duo. How can I make it faster?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a sample of your input file and example of the expected/desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do away with the loop and use a single invocation of awk:

```
awk '
{
    if ($4 == 0) {
       f1 = $1;
       f2 = $2;
       f3 = $3;
       f4 = $4;
       f5 = $5;
    } else {
       f4 = $1;
       f5 = $2;
    }
    printf ("%5.0f%12.4f%12.4f%5.0f%12.4f\n", f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);
}' < $File1 >> $File2
```

That way you're not invoking `awk`, `echo` and `cut` multiple times per line of your input file and are just running a single `awk` process.

Comment: You forgot to filter out the lines starting with `#`, but that would be trivial addition.

Comment: @JanHudec: That line was meant just as a replacement for the while loop, but my answer wasn't that clear.

Comment: But it can replace the grep too. There can be a regular expression before the `{}` block that can handle that.

Comment: Khm, you don't need `cat` (as another useless process in this case) as  `awk` can process files, not just `STDIN` :-)

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai: I've removed the `cat`, though I prefer input and output redirection over letting awk handle the files directly, as I think the resulting code is simpler.  But that's just personal preference.

Comment: @beny23 I don't want to argue about something so trivial. But I am genuinely puzzled why you think `awk ... < $File1` is simpler than `awk ... $File1`.

Comment: In can see where the puzzlement comes from, and I'm a bit puzzled rereading the comment as well.  I think I was thinking of to not opening and closing files inside the awk script (which is a bit out of context, I know) and the fact that using `awk ... < input > output` is a tiny bit more expressive than `awk ... input > output` and I often have awk scripts in long pipe chains, so tend to think of awk as a processor... Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can the whole thing in `awk`, as far as I see, something like

```
awk '/^#/ { print $0 >> "File2" ; getline}
     $0 ! ~ /#/ { if ( $4 == 0 ) { 
                  f1 = $1 ; f2 = $2 ; f3 = $3
                  printf("%5.0f%12.4f%12.4f%5.0f%12.4f\n", f1, f2, f3, $4, $5) >> "File2" }
                  else { printf("%5.0f%12.4f%12.4f%5.0f%12.4f\n", f1, f2, f3, $1, $2) >> "File2" }
                      } INPUTFILE
```

Comment: Don't think that this is functionally equivalent as the shell code only resets `$beginning_line` variable if the 4th column is "0" and reuses the values otherwise.

Comment: @beny23 You're right, I had missed that. Updating the answer (which will be almost the same as yours').